# Troubles Installing Windows 7 via USB. Flat install?

Tags: windows-7, usb, boot, installation, usb-flash-drive

I've been struggling with this for a while.  Windows 7 64-bit Enterprise edition just will not install on my Shuttle K45 system via a USB key.  It hangs out during the install while copying files or while creating the partitions.  The system is pretty standard and low-tech: IDE hard drives, no CD, 2G RAM.

I am not sure what of the problem.  Other than the Shuttle, I have a Apple MacBook Pro.  On the MPB, I am running OS X, and Mint Linux and Windows XP over Parallels.  I have an ISO of Windows 7 that works (I installed it as a Parallels VM to make sure).  I have used UltraISO and the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool to write it to the 8G USB key.  Both seem to copy all the files correctly (with UltraISO, I asked it to verify).  It boots via USB and the install looks just fine.  Until it hangs, most of the time with a copying error of 0x80070241.

I am now trying to figure out if there are other ways I can install Windows 7 on this Shuttle system that has no CD drive.  I've heard about a flat installation, however those all seem to be doing something from within Windows.  I do have access to a Command Prompt from the Windows 7 install.  Does anyone know if/how I can prep the Shuttle hard drive with Windows 7 installation and have Windows 7 install from the hard disk.  I do not have an external enclosure for the IDE HD and I do not have any other system I can hook up to the hard drives.  I do have an external Maxtor OneTouch drive available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the integrity of the ISO

Windows 7 Enterprise x64 MSDN (en_windows_7_enterprise_x64_dvd_x15-70749.iso):

- MD5: 45D3A80E3C73A4B064FF6FEDB4E2DC5B
- SHA1: A89DCE706D527206CB464EF86ACD3A3D13A332DB
- CRC32: D4597619

Try **[WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/)** to prepare the USB flash drive.

Comment: The MD5 checksum matches.  I tried WinToFlash.  It boots from the USB (like the other methods), but then hangs at "Starting Windows" and never reaches the Windows installation.

Comment: can you load the BIOS fail safe/default settings? or change the SATA mode to ACPI in the BIOS and try again.

Comment: It was a hard drive problem.  Something must be bad with the one I'm using.  Switched the HD, the install worked like a charm.